# Generating local interpretations using Shap Kernel Explainer

Tags: machine-learning, out-of-memory, xgboost, interpretation, shap

I am trying to interpret my model using shap kernel explainer. The dataset is of shape (176683, 42). The explainer (xgbexplainer) is successfully modelled and when I use it to generate shap_values, it throws Memory Error.

```
import shap
xgb_explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(trained_model.steps[-1][-1].predict,X_for_shap.values)
shap_val = xgb_explainer.shap_values(X_for_shap.loc[0], nsamples=1)
```

First I used nsamples as default = 2*X_for_shap.shape[2] + 2048, it returned 
**MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (2132, 7420686) and data type float64**

When I set it to nsamples = 1, it runs for indefinite time. Please help me out to understand where I am doing wrong here

[This is the screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgzZl.png)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I dont understand about the kernelexplainer is why we need to impute the missing features with some strategies ( mean , median k means etc ) ? Why not just ignore them and fit a linear learner and compare it with the the model without observing that feature ? P( y| {S} U feature_i ) - P( y | { S } ) ? What kind of added value SHAP approach provides with having the whole features but some of them unknown ?